# Executing a function knowing only its name in node

Tags: node.js

Let's assume I want to execute a function in node but I have only its name (a string).

If  the function is defined in a package (which has been imported) I can do something like this

```
require("lodash")["add"](1, 2);
```

If the function is defined in another file and exported, I can do something like this

**a-function.js**

```
export function aFunction() {
  return console.log("I am a function");
}
```

**anotherJsFile.js**

```
require("./a-function")["aFunction"]();
```

If the function thuogh is defined in the same file where I have the code that wants to call it, I have found only this way to make it work

```
export function anotherFunction() {
  return console.log("I am another function");
}

// the null check guard is added to avoid an "object may be null" Typescript error
(this || {})["anotherFunction"]();
```

Is there a better solution to call a function by name when the function is defined in the same file?

Comment: You can just do `anotherFunction()`.

Comment: You are mixing ES6 module export with `require()` which does not work

Comment: @Wyck I know I can do `anotherFunction()` but I want to achieve the same result just using the name of the function, i.e. `"anotherFunction"`.

Comment: @slebetman I do not understand your comment. The code I show you works but I wanted to know whether there is a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stash your functions in an object that permits finding them by name.

```js
const call = { foo }

function foo() {
  console.log('foo was called.');
}

call['foo']()
```